# Replace substring in state

Tags: php, jquery, mixitup

I use MixItUp (v2.1.11) and I am able to display the active filter which can be multiple filters. I use this function:

```
$(function() {
  $('#miucontainer').on('mixEnd', function(e, state) {
    $('.mixfilter').html(state.activeFilter);
  });
});
```

Whatever filters are chosen are displayed here:

```
<span class="mixfilter"></span>
```

What I would like to achieve is to be able to replace the output title of each chosen filter which for instance can be '.month4' or '.day3'. It would be nice if the user in stead could read 'April' or Wednesday'...

Comment: what is `mixEnd`?

Comment: create an JSON reference data like `{".month1": "Jan", ".month2": "Feb"...}`and use the value against key at the place of `state.activeFilter`.

Comment: mixEnd is when the filters are applied.

Comment: Hi vijayP. I'm too much a beginner in this. Can you please make an example?